# Hibernate mapping resource cannot be opened because it does not exist in a Spring + Hibernate Maven project

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven

I am doing a Spring/Hibernate application using annotations to autowire the Service and Repository layers and have less configuration. All that seems to be done successfully since when I run the app everything seems initialized appropriately.

**Problem**

However, when I add the mapping  resources in my applicationContext-datasource.xml I get an Error stating that the SessionFactory could not be properly initialized because it can seem to find my pojo.hbm.xml file. See:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/dariopardo/jfreechartdemo/pojo/Grid.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

**Setup**

**applicationContext-datasource.xml**

This file is located under **src/main/resources/META_INF/spring**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

  <context:annotation-config/>

  <tx:annotation-driven/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.dariopardo.jfreechartdemo.service">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
 </context:component-scan>

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.dariopardo.jfreechartdemo.dao">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
 </context:component-scan>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserverhere:1521:mydb" />
    <property name="username" value="myusername" />
    <property name="password" value="mypwd" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory for k12-->
<!--<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>                                            
            <value>com/dariopardo/jfreechartdemo/pojo/Grid.hbm.xml</value>               
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region_prefix">hibernate.k12</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</prop>
        <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>  -->
        <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">K12INTEL_DW</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.proxool.pool_alias">pool_K12</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session"></prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"></prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                 classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml                  
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**My POJO**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.dariopardo.jfreechartdemo.pojo">

<class name="Grid">
    <cache usage="read-only" />
    <id name="c1"/>
    <property name="c2"></property>
    <property name="c3"></property>
</class>

<sql-query name="studentAttendanceOver95Pct">
    <return alias="p" class="com.dariopardo.jfreechartdemo.pojo.Grid">
     <return-property name="c1" column="school"/>
     <return-property name="c2" column="at_risk"/>
     <return-property name="c2" column="not_at_risk"/>
     </return>
     My custom sql query goes here
</sql-query>
```

**My DAO layer**

```
@Repository
public class K12DaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements K12DaoManager{

@Autowired
public K12DaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public List<Grid> getAttendanceBySchoolOver95Pct() {

    List<Grid> list =    getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("studentAttendanceOver95Pct");
    return list;
}
}
```

**My Service Layer**

```
@Service
public class K12ManagerImpl implements K12Manager {

@Resource
private K12DaoManager k12DaoManager;

@Override
public List<Grid> studentPctAttendance() {

    return k12DaoManager.getAttendanceBySchoolOver95Pct();
}
}
```

If I comment the the hbm.xml in the mappingResources section everything seems to wire up correctly, but as soon as I bring any hbm.xml file in the mapping resources section the application fails to initialize.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
- Dario

Comment: **UPDATE** I have created a folder strucutre com/dariopardo/jfreechartdemo/pojo and placed the hbm.xml files there and it seem to work. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You specified a location for a mapping file:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>                                            
        <value>com/dariopardo/jfreechartdemo/pojo/Grid.hbm.xml</value>               
    </list>
</property>
```

Hence it is looking for a mapping file under that directory: `com/dariopardo/jfreechartdemo/pojo`. Create this directory, if it is not there, place the file there, and it is going to work.

---

To clean up and decouple your Spring configuration from Hibernate, you can create a separate Hibernate config, where you would specify your mapped classes, mapping locations, and more:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>  

        <mapping package="org.gitpod.startup.bank.*" />
        <mapping class="org.gitpod.startup.bank.MoneyRoll"/>

        <mapping resource="META-INF/conf/hibernate/mapping/startup-bank-named-queries.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then in your Spring config, point a `sessionFactory` bean to the above config location:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:./META-INF/conf/hibernate/startup-hibernate-config.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties"> ... </property>
</bean>
```

This way it'll be easier to manage locations and session factory configuration. You can look at the working example [here](https://github.com/anatoly-polinsky/money-making-project/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/conf/hibernate)

Comment: I already had a package with that name and the files there. That's why I had that reference in the mappingResources property but for some reason when doing **mvn clean tomcat:run** the hbm.xml files where not being put in the classes folder at all. So I solved it by creating another package com.dariopardo.jfreechartdemo.pojo under **src/main/resources**. After that when I did **mvn clean tomcat:run** it worked correctly since the hbm files got moved to the appropriate classes directory. I like your approach better. I will improve my current setup based on your suggestions. Thanks a lot!!